# Function exporting with Roxygen2 is exporting all the functions in my code instead of the one I want

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I am building my own package for the first time and it is finally building with no problems. The problem is that I am exporting only one function with Roxygen2 (6.0.1) as it is the only one to be used but when I build and load my package, all the function present in it are exported. (When I look with package:: )

I've been searching for similar occurrences but didn't find any

Here is the Roxygen comments just before the function:

```
#' Do a plot
#'
#' @param region a GRange object with chr, start, end
#' @param genome a character vector "hg19","hg38" or "mm10"
#' @param BAM a path to the BAM related csv input file
#' @param BED a path to the BED related csv input file
#' @param avgTrack a logical indicating if the average track should be present or not
#' @param geneTrack a logical indicating if the gene track should be present or not
#' @param max a vector of number containing the maximum of each BAM track
#'
#' @export
myfunction <- function(){}
```

And here is the NAMESPACE that is generated by Roxygen2:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(myfunction)
importFrom(GenomicRanges,findOverlaps)
importFrom(IRanges,elementNROWS)
importFrom(IRanges,splitAsList)
importFrom(S4Vectors,List)
importFrom(S4Vectors,queryHits)
importFrom(S4Vectors,subjectHits)
importFrom(S4Vectors,subjectLength)
importFrom(biomaRt,getBM)
importFrom(grDevices,hcl)
importFrom(graphics,axis)
importFrom(graphics,legend)
importFrom(graphics,lines)
importFrom(graphics,par)
importFrom(graphics,plot)
importFrom(graphics,plot.new)
importFrom(graphics,rect)
importFrom(graphics,segments)
importFrom(graphics,text)
importFrom(rbamtools,bamCount)
importFrom(rbamtools,bamReader)
importFrom(rbamtools,getRefCoords)
importFrom(utils,read.table)
```

when I do mypackage:: I should have only one function showing (mypackage::myfunction) by I get all the functions that are in my code instead.

Comment: do you have `#' @export` on all your functions?

Comment: No, Just on the first one, but the first one is using all the other functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get all the functions that are in my code instead"? Are all your functions in the NAMESPACE, or just those you've imported?

Comment: So I have one main function that I want visible when someone load the package. This particular function is tagged with the  `#' @export`. Then I have 30 other functions that are used by the main function but that are not tagged with `#' @export`. Those are to be loaded with the package but I don't want them to be usable by the user.

Comment: Are you using RStudio to build the package? Do you have `Build > Configure Build Tools > Generate Documentation with Roxygen > Configure > Install and Restart` checked? (sometimes this gets reset)

Comment: Just followed the instructions, restarted R and Rstudio. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: Is your package on github?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to put it anywhere that's why I replaced the name of the function and package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some reasons when I modify my NAMESPACE from `export(myfunction)` to `export("myfunction")` I get the expected result.

It can also be achieved by using `#' @export "myfunction"`with the Roxygen2 syntax.